# R: Replacing specific elements in a list with values from another list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list with 2 entries that have 2151 elements each (example below), I am trying to append the first 617 elements of the 2nd entry/row with corrected values from a new data frame.

```
    350       351       352       353       354       355       356       357      358
0.1605838 0.1563904 0.1560198 0.1562126 0.1538623 0.1481579 0.1419231 0.1399439 0.1381211
```

I am trying to take the values within test.multiply and overwrite the first 617 elements of the 2nd entry/row of the initial list. I have tried to concatenate segments from these two datasets together but with no success, the result is a list that has 1534 elements with the following warning:

`Warning message: In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter`

Here's my script:

```
file.dir <- system.file.after[25]#("system.file[1]",package="FieldSpectra")
spec <- read.asd(file.dir,out.dir='~',start.wave=350,end.wave=2500,step.size=1)

# Get info from file header
spec <- read.asd(file.dir,out.dir='~')

# Correct the anomaly at 967 nm
spec.df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, spec)
spec.split <- spec.df[,1:617]
spec.jump <- spec.df[,966]
spec.value <- spec.df[,967]
spec.divide <- spec.jump[2]
spec.multiply <-spec.value[2] 

test.divide <- spec.split[2,]/spec.divide # selects every row and 2nd to last columns
test.multiply <- test.divide*spec.multiply

#1st attempt
apend.spec <- Map(c,test.multiply, spec[618:2151])
# 2nd attempt
apend.spec <- Map(c,test.multiply[,1:617], spec.df[[2]][618:2151])
```

This clearly doesn't work, and I was wondering if anyone had a different method or function to successfully replace the original values?

Comment: could you show  your two lists? Seems to me that youve a vector rather than a list

Comment: Sorry, but do you mean the values within the lists?

Comment: just do a `dput(head(your_list))` and paste the results here

Comment: I did that and it gave me this (abbreviated output):

`> dput(head(spec))
list(Wavelength = c(350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 
359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 
372, 373, 374...Spectra = structure(c(0.160583822326284, 
0.156390436445402, 0.156019849984151, 0.156212636946999, 0.153862263239393.Dim = 2151L`

Comment: `list[[2]][1:617] <- correct values`

Comment: Thank you, that worked and replaced the old values!